# HBase get multiple distinct rowids?

Tags: java, scala, get, hbase

I am using HBase JAVA/Scala API and have a list of rowids List(1,2,5) and want to retrieve rows corresponding to those ids at the same time.

val getOne = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1"))

Let's me access only 1 row and I don't want to do get(1) get(2) and get(5) sequentially (latency).

How would I do all at once and iterate through the return set later?

If API does not offer it what is the next best way?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is easy
list of gets
Result[] get(List gets) throws IOException

Answer (score 0):

You just have to construct multiple "Get" requests and use the below method from the HTable.

```
  Result[] get(List<Get> gets)
```

Link to the javadoc is [here](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#get-java.util.List-).